# Virtual synthesizer or piano roll with controllable number of keys per octave?

Tags: tuning, midi, synthesizer, microtonality, virtual-instrument

I am interested in performing and composing in non-twelve tone scales, such as [19-EDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19_equal_temperament) (aka 19-TET) or [31-EDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/31_equal_temperament) (aka 31-TET).  While there are virtual synthesizers that allow you to play microtonal scales, all virtual synthesizers I have seen have 12 notes as part of their user interface.  It also seems like all MIDI sequencers have 12 notes in their interface.

**For 19-EDO, I want to be able to play 19 keys per octave on a virtual piano as in the image below!**

[image]

Is writing on a single piano roll with 19 notes per octave possible in any existing software?   Are there virtual synthesizers with a controllable number of keys per octave?

The hacky solution I have working right now uses Propellerhead Reason with the Microtune plugin and the Distributor via [this Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXhvwFN9To8).  For 19-EDO (and any tuning with between 12 and 24 notes per octave) I  use two differently tuned virtual instruments to play all the notes in one octave!  For 19-EDO, I have one tuned for the 12 black keys and one instrument for the 7 white keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sound sources you can find information [here](http://xenharmonic.wikispaces.com/List+of+Microtonal+Software+Plugins?responseToken=ea7d57e86cf1b02f83ed36c98035c942). In my opinion, u-he plugins are especially great.

As for visual feedback - you can change your pianoroll layout to different tunnings in [Reaper](https://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?t=146780).